# Javascript working in Firefox but not Chrome after adding effect to fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I have added an effect for my header and navigation bar in my website and now the problem is that it's working in Firefox but not Chrome. The effect is working fine on the header but not on the navigation links. I am trying to figure out what's wrong but everything seems to be fine.

Here's the link to my site:
http://sabirmb.com/Parallax

Here's the Javascript Code added to fullpage.js that makes the desired effect on my header and navigation. Basically the effect is to make add color changes transition to my header:

```
function activateMenuElement(name) {
    if(options.menu) {
        $(options.menu).find(ACTIVE_SEL).removeClass(ACTIVE);
        $(options.menu).find('[data-menuanchor="'+name+'"]').addClass(ACTIVE);
        if(name != 'home') {
            $('header').removeClass('colourful');
            $('ul#navlist li a').removeClass('colourful');
        } else {        
            $('#section0').load('index.html #slider');
            $('header').addClass('colourful');
            $('ul#navlist li a').addClass('colourful');
        }
    }
}
```

I only added the following part to the script to get it working but it doesn't work on Chrome for some (only the nav a links):

```
if(name != 'home') {
    $('header').removeClass('colourful');
    $('ul#navlist li a').removeClass('colourful');
} else {        
    $('#section0').load('index.html #slider');
    $('header').addClass('colourful');
    $('ul#navlist li a').addClass('colourful');
}
```

Hoping to find some help. Thanks

Comment: TypeError: element.find(...).get(...) is undefined
Source File: http://sabirmb.com/Parallax/fullPage.js
Line: 1880 You should first fix all js errors

Comment: I don't understand why this error is there since I didn't touch it. Do you think the if statement could have tiggerred this error?

Comment: I can't say. But until you have js errors, you could expect some of your code to not work.

Comment: I see. I'll try to see what's wrong

Comment: The thing I noticed was that it works for me on links I have not clicked on.  Links I have clicked on do not change color as it's using the #headNav a:link, a:visited {
  color: #000;
} from line 70 of style.css  I think what's happening is that Firefox is ignoring the a:visited and chrome is honoring it.  Try setting a:link and a:visited, or remove a:visited from style.css.